# Running a process in the background

Tags: bash

I am trying to Write a script that demonstrates server-client communication.I am stuck at the part where i have to run 2 clients simultaneously.

I tried executing 1 client application in the background via something like this:

```
./SocketClient &
```

I tried running the other normally so that the user can interact with it normally.

It doesn't seem to work since the background Client app is asking for input.

So my question is,how can i run it in background and ignore it indefinitely?

Comment: Try detaching it from its controlling terminal: `nohup ./SocketClient &`

Comment: I am looking into it.I kinda need to reattach it later so maybe i should use screen

Comment: Ah, ok. Then you might also be interested in the old `CTRL-Z` control sequence. You can bring such a job back (into foreground) with the `fg` command afterwards.

Comment: I.e., you may want to send a `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP`.